# Most efficient search method to make sure git commit id not in list of existing commit ids?

Tags: python, git, search

I am working on a project where I am routinely mining our `Gerrit` repos to pull commit info.  I want to make this an incremental load, and I am trying to figure out the best way to do so.

My thought is to limit the query to all changes that have been modified in the last 3-7 days, and then run their commit id's against the id's already in the database.

Which search method would be the most efficient to check for existing id's?

Here is an example of an id:

```
7399eee93ed45304e756f7c4510401c442f46527
```

Comment: A simple scan. It's `O(n)`. Unless you've indexed your ids, e.g. stored them in a dictionary, in which case it's `O(1)`.

Comment: Could you explain how I would index them?  I like O(1) better;)